# python - compare string with boolean

Tags: string, python-3.x, comparison

I came across a strange behaviour of python comparing a string with True/False.

I thought that python would print in the following:

```
if "Test" == True:
    print("Hello1")
```

but it does not.
So I wrote some Test cases and I do not understand some of them.

```
if "Test" == True:
    print("Hello1")

if "Test" == False:
    print("Hello2")

#This I understand
if bool("Test") == True:
    print("Hello3")

#This I understand too    
if bool("") == False:
    print("Hello4")

if "Test":
    print("Hello5")
```

**Output**

```
>> Hello3
>> Hello4
>> Hello5
```

So I do not understand:

- If Hello1 is not printed why is not Hello2 either?
- Why does Hello5 get printed, is the cast to bool("Test") made implicit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first two comparisons, you are checking whether the string `"Test"` has the same value as the object `True` or `False`. This is a value comparison.

If they have a different type, the comparison will return `False`. You can see this also when comparing lists, numbers etc.: `[1]==1` (false), `(1,)==[1]` (false).

In the third and fourth comparisons, you are still doing a value comparison, but since both sides are of the same type (boolean), it will compare the values.

`Hello5` is printed because it is not the null string `""`. You can see this by trying `"Test" != None`, which returns `True`.

While it is a comparison to `None` when it comes to most classes(`None` is Python's null value), Python's standard data types are compared to their "null" value, which are:

- The empty string `""` for strings,
- `[]` for lists (similary `()` for tuples, `{}` for dictionaries),
- `0` for ints and floats,

just like a boolean comparison. Therefore it is not wrong to think of `if expression` as an implicit cast to `if bool(expression)`.

What is going on under the hood is the evaluation of the [`__non-zero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)(python2.x) or [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__)(python3.x) method of the class.

Comment: If you improve your answer to contain the object comparison too it is actually better then the on of user762353. An anwser should always stand on its own.

Comment: @M.T The first four comparison are *not* comparing objects, but values. To compare objects (or in other words, identity) would be `"Test" is True` not `"Test" == True`. I think this is what you mean, but your verbiage is ambiguous. Please clarify your answer for future users.

Comment: @M.T Also, another correction: `None` is not (strictly speaking or otherwise) a class; it is a singleton. In other words, it in an instance of class `NoneType` that has only one allowed instance: `None`. You should remove the statement that it is a class from your answer as it is false information. Other than the things I mentioned, this is a very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Hello1, Hello2 and Hello5 there is an object comparison and not boolean comparions.

That means that
the string-object `"Test"` is not the same as object `True` ("Hello1")
the string object `"Test"` is not the same as object `False`("Hello2")
but the string object `"Test"` is not `None` ("Hello5")